# Send byte through Telnet in Python

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

In a Python script, I need to send a single byte through Telnet, with value 0x06, for example. However, the write function from `telnetlib` (`Telnet.write(buffer)`) only takes strings as argument.

The conversion using `str(0x06)` does not work, as its output converts the number to an array of chars, while what I want is a char whose value is 0x06.

So basically, how does one send a single byte through Telnet using Python?

Comment: try `\x06` should work

Comment: Or `b'\x06'` if this is for python3 - you should mention which python version you're working with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Telnet.write( chr(27) )
```

or

```
Telnet.write( "\x1b" )
```

to write one single byte for instance.

Comment: It works! Thanks!
For extra points: What if the number does not fit in 1 bytes, and 2 bytes are needed?

Comment: Define a format like 4 bytes. Then fill it up with 0 for 1 for instance: 0001. for 11 it should look like 0011. You can use a formatted string to write this.